# How do I associate my value with its key when writing to Firebase in Swift 3?

Tags: json, swift, firebase, key-value

I'm working with `Swift` and `Firebase` to write profile info to my FireBase Database.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: userEmail!, password: userPassword!) { (user, error) in

                    self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


                    self.ref?.child("Users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).setValue(String(describing: user))
                    self.ref?.child("Users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("User Email").setValue([userEmail])
```

I expect the Database to read as:

> UID
>
> ---UserFirstName: "Insert Name Here"

But instead I get:

> UID
>
> ---UserFirstName
>
> ------0: "Insert Name Here"

I know I'm just missing something basic here. this is my first shot at Swift. Nothing else I've read seems to reference this issue. I'm sure I'm just not properly representing the "key-value" relationship correctly in the syntax of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by altering my code to look like this:

```
self.ref?.child("Users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).updateChildValues(["User Email": userEmail!])
```

the change to `updateChildValues` allowed me to not overwrite myself under the node each time, and the `(["User Email": userEmail!])` piece allows me to attribute the value directly to the key.